# How would be an algorithm to simulate human interaction?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Let's suppose that androids which are physically alike humans are a reality.
What would be an algorithm to make it interact with human beings if we want it to: 
1) be indistinguishable from regular people in behavior 
2) be as equally friendly to everyone as possible?

I understand that it is very hard to write an algorithm like that. I can, however, imagine an android simulating human behavior fairly well with some sort of machine learning technique.
But how would we train it? The act of collecting data would also be a big big problem.
Which machine learning technique would be ideal?

Comment: Interesting question, but very broad

Comment: I am afraid your two requirements are contradictory. (Not counting the fact that no one came any close to such a goal in 50 years of AI research.)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider requirement 1 to be a hard requirement, such an algorithm would beat the [Turing Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) at least to some extent, so it would be a pretty advanced (world-class) algorithm.

Your problem basically equates to beating the Turing Test, so check the linked article to see the scientific literature produced by people working on this problem.

Assuming massive data availability and processing power are basically unbounded, I believe an Artificial Neural Network would be the best runner-up to base such an algorithm on.

Comment: I didn`t know of the Turing Test. It`s very interesting. Thank you for the indication.